# Which is the cheapest ferry to Jeju in South Korea?

Tags: budget, ferries, south-korea, jeju

A few months ago [I dug up lots of information on getting to Jeju in South Korea](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3442/jeju-island-new-natural-wonder-of-the-world-how-to-get-there), but I didn't find the prices.

Most of the websites are only in Korean so I'm throwing this one open to all our expert contributors. **Which of the ferries to Jeju is cheapest?**

Logically it could be the shortest / quickest. But you never know if that might involve a more modern or more luxurious ferry or a more expensive to run hydrofoil or something.

- **Wando** is probably the shortest crossing.
- **Mokpo** could also be short but the information I found at the time was inconsistent and varied by several hours.

<sup>(I'll be hitchhiking and nearly broke so I have no constraints as far as time, frequency, location - just price.)</sup>

Comment: did you have any luck with this?

Comment: As it happened I never left Seoul after resting my hitchhiking injuries from Bulgaria/Turkey. But I've talked about it to a few people and Wando does seem to be the cheapest ferry.

Answer (score 3):

[visitkorea.or.kr](http://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/TR/TR_EN_5_1_5_1.jsp) has some information on routes and prices to Jeju.

The cheapest rates they quote are KRW 30,000 for Mokpo-Jeju and KRW 26,250 for Wando-Jeju.

So yes, Wando seems to be the cheapest option.

However, I travelled the Mokpo route in summer 2011. Back then my hostel host was able to get me a free shuttle bus from Gwangju to Mokpo.

Answer (score 2):

I found this website helpful in actually producing fare prices:

http://www.aferry.com/timetable/WandoChujaHanilExpress.htm

I found that I could do a return sailing for 50 euros. If you look around the site you can try other operators.

[image: Sample image from the site]

Comment: edited the screenshot in for you :)